# Can search engine fetch/index website that using ipv6 only?

Tags: seo, googlebot, web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, ipv6

I see some host providers offer cheap server but only support ipv6. I want to rent it, but I am still considering the SEO impact.

Can google and other search engine crawl and index it? If yes, will it have same qualification rank as ipv4?

Comment: Only 30% of your users would be able to get to your site because that's how many Google reports is being able to support IPv6. Forget about SEO, you're throwing away 70% of your traffic if you go that route. https://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/statistics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEORoundTable.com quotes John Mueller of Google in 2017 as saying,

> Google can handle sites on IPv6 & HTTP/2 all just fine with Google web
> search

, however he goes on to say you should still support IP4 and HTTP/1x.  If  you're not sure if you can use IP6 only, test with Google's Fetch or URL inspection.

They go on to quote Mueller as saying

> If Googlebot can access it normally, and you're seeing a change in
> ranking, it's possible that the infrastructure change isn't related to
> the ranking change.

Unfortunately, they point to a server than has been redirected and appears to have lost John's original post so I can't point you to his original statement.

Comment: Is there any official source for this that can be verified? And how can we verify that Search console and GoogleBot works over IPv6 without disabling IPv4?